# How do i send a message in a specific channel when my bot start

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like to send a message in a channel when my bot starts here is my code

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running")
    activity = discord.Game(name="!test", type=3)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
    #issue starts here
    client.getchannel(944607968211652631)
    await client.channel.send("I am online")
```

I have tried a different way aswell

```
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running")
    activity = discord.Game(name="!test", type=3)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
    on = client.getchannel(944607968211652631)
    await on.channel.send("I am online")
```

but this also has not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using client.getchannel which doesn't exist, use [`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel). It returns a channel which can be used to send messages.
Example:

```py
channel = client.get_channel(id)
await channel.send("hi i've started")
```